# How to generate modelformset based on records in another model?

Tags: django, django-forms

Suppose this is my model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Answer(models.Model): 
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=1)
```

I want to create a modelformset from **Answer** model which automatically generates a form based on the number of records in **Question** model.

```
model_formset = modelformset_factory(Answer, fields=('answer',), widgets = { 'answer': RadioSelect(choices=RATING_CHOICES),})

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = model_formset(request.POST)
            if (form.is_valid()):
                #
                #
                #
```

Answer (score 0):

See djangodocs for [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/models/#modelformset-factory).

```
model_formset = modelformset_factory(
    Answer,
    fields=('answer',),
    widgets = {'answer': RadioSelect(choices=RATING_CHOICES),},
    extra=0,
    max_num={your_qstn_count},
    min_num=={your_qstn_count},
    validate_min=True,
    validate_max=True
)
```

Comment: I do not want just to generate based on objects. With each form generated, an id tie to that particular formset.

Comment: For example, 
formset 1 = question.1
formset 2 = question.2
...